# How load a URL when open page with webbrowser

Tags: windows-phone-7

i made a app for windows phone 7, the app has 2 pages, one with a button and another with a webbrownser, when i press the button in page one, it goes to page 2.. ok so far, but i cant make the URL load when the page 2 opens.
i cant find a way. please help! thanks

my code

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Net;
       using System.Windows;
       using System.Windows.Controls;
       using System.Windows.Documents;
       using System.Windows.Input;
       using System.Windows.Media;
       using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
       using System.Windows.Shapes;
       using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

       namespace PhoneApp2
   {
public partial class Page2 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }




    private void navigate()
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute));

    }




 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to navigate the Browser as soon as page is loaded, use following mechanism.
You can do this by firing the `Navigate` event of `WebBrowser` as soon, the new page is navigated and loaded.

```cs
    // Constructor
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page1_Loaded);
    }

    private void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Fire the Navigation Event of Browser here
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute));
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: just one thing more, when i put google page it goes right... but when i put some other URL without "WWW" it wont open.. you know why ?